# Scala type mismatch when method return type is added

Tags: scala

I have a method that runs when there is no specified return type, but as soon as the return type is added, a mismatch error is given. The return type of the returned value is the same.

This works fine:

```
def get_csv_page(url: String){
    scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).getLines.drop(1).toList
 }
```

Returns:

```
res2: List[String]
```

But adding : List[String] causes mismatch:

```
def get_csv_page(url: String) = List[String]{
    scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).getLines.drop(1).toList
}

:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[String]
 required: String
        scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).getLines.drop(1).toList
                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a syntax error, it should be a `:` to specify the return type and then an `=`:

```
def get_csv_page(url: String): List[String] = {
    scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).getLines.drop(1).toList
}
```

---

What you have right now is trying to construct a List literal, which is why it is wanting you to provide a single String for an element of your list.